# Glide does not load the images when there are two types of view in the RecyclerView.Adapter onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm trying to populate a RecyclerView.Adapter with 2 types of views with getItemViewType, but I can not get the images from the URL with Glide. If only I put a load if you show me Glide images in item 2.
Help me fix it.

There are two types of views, each one has an image and different data to the others, depending on the type of view is assigned a different cardview.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = LogUtils.makeLogTag(ItemAdapter.class);

private List<Object> items;
private final int TYPE1 = 0, TYPE2 = 1;

public ItemAdapter(List<Object> items) {
    this.items=items;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.items.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (items.get(position) instanceof ItemType1) {
        return TYPE1;
    } else if (items.get(position) instanceof ItemType2) {
        return TYPE2;
    }
    return -1;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE1:
            View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item_type_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ItemType1ViewHolder(v1);
            break;
        case TYPE2:
            View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item_type_2, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ItemType2ViewHolder(v2);
            break;
        default:
            View v = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ItemType1ViewHolder(v);
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case TYPE1:
            ItemType1ViewHolder vh1 = (ItemType1ViewHolder) holder;
            configureItemType1ViewHolder(vh1, position);
            break;
        case TYPE2:
            ItemType2ViewHolder vh2 = (ItemType2ViewHolder) holder;
            configureItemType2ViewHolder(vh2, position);
            break;
        default:
            ItemType1ViewHolder vh = (ItemType1ViewHolder) holder;
            configureItemType1ViewHolder(vh, position);
            break;
    }
}

private void configureItemType1ViewHolder(ItemType1ViewHolder vh1, int position) {
    ItemType1 itemType1 = (ItemType1) items.get(position);
    if (itemType1 != null) {
        Glide.with(vh1.itemImage1.getContext())
                .load(itemType1.getItemImage())
                .into(vh1.itemImage1);
        //vh1.itemImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bgeneral);
    }
}

private void configureItemType2ViewHolder(ItemType2ViewHolder vh2, int position) {
    ItemType2 itemType2 = (ItemType2) items.get(position);
    if (itemType2 != null) {
        Glide.with(vh2.itemImage2.getContext())
                .load(itemType2.getItemImage())
                .into(vh2.itemImage2);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Glide in bind function in your viewholder instead this way:

```
 public class ItemType1ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
 {
  ImageView image;

 public ItemType1ViewHolder (View view)
 {
    super(view);
    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
 }

 public void bind(final ItemAdapter adapter, int position)
{
      // you should make items public and pass a context to your adapter

      Object object=(Object) adapter.items.get(position);
      Glide.with(adapter.context)
            .load(object.getItemImage())
            .into(image);

}
```

}